# How to define a method in the superclass so that it will be compatible with any subclass?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a few classes:

```
class Sup:
    def meth (self, ?????):
        pass

class Sub1(Sup):
    def meth (self, foo = 1):
        ...

class Sub2(Sup):
    def meth (self, bar = 2, baz = 3):
        ...
```

what do I replace `?????` in `Sup.meth` with?

Basically, I want something similar to the ignored `&rest` lambda-list keyword in Lisp to pacify `arguments-differ/Arguments number differs from overridden method` warning.

What I tried:

1. adding `**kwargs` to `Sup.meth` - did not change anything
2. annotating `Sub*.meth` with `# pylint: disable=arguments-differ` - works, but ugly.

PS. `Sup` is an abstract class to collect stats; `Sub*` are different methods to do that; `meth` prints the object with different bells and whistles.

Comment: Do you call `Sup.meth` from any subclass? Python doesn't enforce identical signatures for overridden methods, so I'm not entirely clear on what the problem is.

Comment: I never call `Sup.meth`; I just want to pacify `pylint`.

Comment: Well one option would be to `# pylint: disable=arguments-differ`! You can use `**kwargs` for *"arbitrary keyword arguments"*, whether `pylint` would accept that I can't check right now.

Comment: `adding **kwargs to Sup.meth - did not work` be more explicit?

Comment: Given that they seem to take unrelated arguments, should they really be the same method? The point of having a method on the superclass and subclasses is that code calling it shouldn't have to care what specific instance it has; this isn't true if there are different arguments. Could you provide a less abstract example?

Comment: Another option is to disable the warning in your Pylint configuration file. You can find some basic information about them on their website: [http://docs.pylint.org/run.html]. And you can use the --generate-rcfile argument to help you generate that file. Their website suggests that you can make Pylint load the file from the project directory, although I didn't get that working. It might stop looking after the first configuration file it finds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that pylint has... unusual opinions about many Python features.  It thinks `some_function(*list_of_args)` is "bad magic", for example (W0124).

When you and pylint will *never* agree on a "problem", the solution isn't weird comments in your code, but silencing that message forever in `~/.pylintrc`.  (`pylint --generate-rcfile` will spit out a sample config file that you can edit yourself.) There, you can set:

- A regex for deliberately-unused variables: `dummy-variables-rgx=_$|__$`
- Regexes for variable, class, and constant names: `function-rgx=[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}$`
- Silence individual warnings or whole message categories (one of "IRCWEF"): `disable=I0011,W0142,R`.

`~/.pylintrc` is the *only* way I've found you can disable some things --- like "`I0011: "Locally disabling %s"`, because locally silencing I0011 itself generates another I0011 message (which is downright sadistic).

For projects, I typically create a one-line shell script to further disable things I don't intend to fix:

```
#!/bin/bash

pylint --output=colorized --disable=C0103 *.py | less -R -
#  :C0103 (invalid-name): *Invalid name "%s" for type %s (should match %s)*
```

Translation: "I already know the previous guy had his own naming convention, so please don't tell me another 8000 times."

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `*args` for positional arguments and `**kwargs` for keyword arguments.

More information is available here: [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Comment: @sds I guess my reply is that you should either establish a more strict class structure, or ignore the warning. PyLint will happily complain about perfectly valid code because it violates some minor style convention. Adding `**kwargs` semi-rectifies the readability problem, but it still leaves an inconsistent class interface, which PyLint rightly detects. If this is really important, you _might_ consider using `**kwargs` for the other methods too. But that has its own readability disadvantages...
tl;dr: don't fight PyLint. Write readable code.